# App crashes when opening a picture - myImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm new to iOS development trying out Swift 2.0 (so I can easily run the code on my phone with Xcode 7 without a developer account) and ran into some problems with the tutorial that I'm using. I'm trying to create a simple photo gallery app where you can view photos.

I can see the photo gallery, but when I click on a photo I get an error: 
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386)INVOP,subcode=0x0)` and the output is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

The line of code in question is `myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`

Any suggestions?

My entire function is:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        myImageView.image = chosenImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: And where is `myImageView` defined, and how is it connected to your image view instance?

Comment: I have it declared right at the beginning of the class
`@IBOutlet weak var myImageView:UIImageView!`

This is the tutorial I was following: http://makeapppie.com/2014/12/04/swift-swift-using-the-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library/

Comment: And connected it to an instance how? Show the code. It sounds like it isn't connected to the instance, and presumably the instance is defined in your storyboard?

Comment: Can I post large snips of code in the comments? This is the tutorial I was following (http://makeapppie.com/2014/12/04/swift-swift-using-the-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library/) and all I've changed from their view controller is the function that I have in my OP. Their whole code is at the bottom

Comment: @Wain Yup, you were right about the instance. Thanks!